# Plotting Leibniz series

Tags: r, data-visualization

[image]

How to plot Leibniz series in R for above? Basically I am looking for R commands.

Comment: "Give me R commands" without a statistical problem to solve is off topic here. With some changes it might be on topic at StackOverflow or on SuperUser. However, you seem to be just doing class work, in which case you should really contribute more than you have. Some relevant R functions would include  `cumsum` and `plot`. See their help

Answer (score 2):

Let's see if I can cobble together an exact transliteration using `Reduce` which allows cumulative function applications to series. The `:`-operator is also quite handy for building the underlying series:

```
 plot( pi/4 - Reduce( 'sum' ,
                      (-1)^(0:200)*(1/(1+2*(0:200))), 
                      acc=TRUE) ) # preserves the intermediate values
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a homework assignment because I googled the same thing lol.  I will help without giving away the answer because you'll learn better if you actually work through the assignment.

At this point, my class did not learn the `Reduce` function so as an alternative, what you can do is create a function that implements the series: 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 +......, for n iterations (n = 200).

Have the function return a list of values (this would be your y-axis values) and you can plot those for 0:200 (your x-axis values). Then plot a second line graph with y-axis as pi/4 minus the values returned by the function.